# Love of Home and Friends—like the ridge behind a Bunker! (Meaning)

Tags: meaning, translation, connotation, metaphors, literature

I'm translating a fable by George Ade called "The Fable of the Visitor Who Got a Lot for Three Dollars." In the following extract, the phrenologist is telling his customer how he is based on the form of his head:

> "Well, well!" said the Learned Phrenologist "Enough Benevolence here to do a family of Eight. Courage? I guess yes! Dewey's got the same kind of a Lump right over the Left Ear. Love of Home and Friends—like the ridge behind a Bunker!"

My issue is with the phrase "Love of Home and Friends—like the ridge behind a Bunker!" I assume "like the ridge behind a Bunker" is a metaphor, but I feel like I can't get the meaning. Would you please help me with this?

Comment: Is the analogy *physical*? The Lump is the ridge, and the Left Ear is the Bunker?

Comment: It's clearly a physical feature of the head, felt and seen by the phrenologist. A pronounced ridge.

Comment: Why is bunker capitalized?

Comment: Because Ade seems to randomly capitalize words. Possibly for comic effect.

Answer (score 2):

Bunker in this case is a hole in the ground, sometimes called a foxhole, used in trench warfare. The ridge is the dug out dirt piled up behind it. He's just saying it's a Big Lump.

Comment: As Merriam-Webster defines it, "a protective embankment or dugout". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bunker

Comment: Actually I think it relates to a golf bunker, based on [another Ade fable](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/20510/20510-h/20510-h.htm), "The scoffer who fell hard and the woman sitting by", which describes a calamitous golf game causing someone to quit the sport entirely: "he tore up the Medal Score, gave all the Clubs to the Caddy, and standing on the grassy Summit of the tall Ridge guarding the Bunker, he had lifted a grimy Paw and uttered the Vow of Renunciation." Same idea, though: a ridge next to a depression.

Comment: I thought that a bunker in trench warfare was something much more strongly engineered than a foxhole. To me a foxhole is a small hastily dug hole but a bunker is larger, usually roofed, and often has supported sides. I'm not even sure that the excavated soil is normally placed _behind_ a bunker, I suspect that it would be more likely to be built up in front of it to provide more protection. I'm in agreement with @StuartF in suspecting that the reference is to a golf bunker.